# C++ : Meaning of const char*const*

Tags: c++, pointers, function-prototypes, function-parameter

In one of the C++ programs, I saw a function prototype : `int Classifier::command(int argc, const char*const* argv)`

What does `const char*const* argv` mean? Is it the same as `const char* argv[]`?
Does `const char** argv` also mean the same?

Comment: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: Read (mainly) from right to left, pointer to a const pointer to (const char).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not the same as `const char *argv[]`. The `const` prohibits modifications of the dereferenced value at the particular level of dereferencing:

```
**argv = x; // not allowed because of the first const
*argv = y; // not allowed because of the second const
argv = z; // allowed because no const appears right next to the argv identifier
```

Answer (score 22):

From the [C++ Super-FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ptr-vs-ptr-const):

> Read the pointer declarations right-to-left.
>
> - `const X* p` means "`p` points to an `X` that is `const`": the `X` object can't be changed [via `p`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#ptr-to-const-aliasing).
> - `X* const p` means "`p` is a `const` pointer to an `X` that is `non-const`": you can't change the pointer `p` itself, but you can change the `X` object [via `p`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#ptr-to-const-aliasing).
> - `const X* const p` means "p is a `const` pointer to an `X` that is `const`": you can't change the pointer `p` itself, nor can you change the `X` object [via `p`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#ptr-to-const-aliasing).
>
> And, oh yea, did I mention to read your pointer declarations right-to-left?

`const char * const *` is the same as `char const * const *`: a (non-const) pointer to a const pointer to a const char.

`const char *` is the same as `char const *`: a (non-const) pointer to a const char.

`const char * *` is the same as `char const * *`: a (non-const) pointer to a (non-const) pointer to a const char.

Answer (score 4):

`const char*const* argv` means "pointer to constant pointer to constant `char`". It's not "the same" as `const char *argv[]`, but it is compatible to some extent:

```
void foo(const char *const *argv);

void bar(const char **argv)
{
    foo(argv);
}
```

compiles just fine. (The reverse wouldn't compile without a `const_cast`.)

Answer (score 2):

A pointer that does not change to a string that does not change:

```
const char* aString ="testString";

aString[0] = 'x';   // invaliv since the content is const
aString = "anotherTestString"; //ok, since th content doesn't change

const char const* bString = "testString";
bString [0] = 'x'; still invalid
bString = "yet another string"; // now invalid since the pointer now too is const and may not be changed.
```

Comment: `const char const* bString = "testString";` is the same thing as `const char* aString ="testString";`. If you wanted your second example to be correct, you would put the `const` after the `*` like so: `const char *const aString ="testString";`

Answer (score 0):

```
const char*const* a;
```

Basically says:
`a` is a pointer to an unchangeable const char pointer.

So this would be a valid code:

```
const const const char*const*const* a;
```